# How to read and write data into BLE devices in android?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, android-ble

I Scanned the BLE device and its displaying device name, RSSI value and MAC address.

How to check whether BLE device has data or no?

And how to read and write data from/to BLE Device?

Can you please give me an example?

Comment: That all depend on the device your talking about.

Comment: This all depends on what services are implemented on GATT, with what access parameters and configurations. This is a very vague question and needs to specify the ble module being talked about.